# Dynamically adding ASP.Net userControl with Google Map

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, user-controls

İ downloaded gMap.dll and created an userControl which include Map.When i used this userControl in a aspx page directly there is no problem.But When i insert this usercontrol to page dynamically it only gives a gray box.This is my dynamically adding code

`Control userControl = LoadControl("kcfinder/upload/userControl/googleMap.ascx");
userControlDiv.Controls.Add(userControl);`

So, are some components not loaded with this method ?What is the problem?Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it in the Pre-Init method. Then refer to it as late as possible in the page life cycle, eg: Pre-Prender(...)